# create Self Hosted Integration Runtime on Azure Windows VM

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions, azure-vm

I am using an Azure DevOps pipeline that is basically a series of steps that call PowerShell scripts that take in parameter values and within the PS script the "Az module commands" are called - these commands create the infrastructure on Azure.

For example...

1. Create a public static IP address - this I can do.
2. Create a NIC and link static IP address - this I can do.
3. Create a Synapse Workspace and 'Self Integration Runtime' - this I can do accept link Synapse SHIRT to the self-hosted integrated runtime on the Azure VM.
4. Create a Windows VM (datacenter 2019) - this I can do.
5. Create a Azure Windows VM self-hosted integration runtime via devOps pipeline???

I now want to create a step in the devOPs pipeline (maybe an ARM template or PS script that calls an Az module) that automatically installs the 'self hosted integration runtime' on the Azure Windows VM - the VM is attached to an Vnet/subnet. The runtime on the Azure VM will be linked to the Synapse runtime. (note I am not using Data Factory)

I have read the following. But can't workout if setting up a runtime on the Azure VM and Synapse and linking them is possible and if it can be automated in a devOPs pipeline?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#considerations-for-using-a-self-hosted-ir

The below link is very near to what I want to achieve....

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.compute/vms-with-selfhost-integration-runtime

Answer (score 0):

Have added one manually step once the devOps pipeline finishes.

Open RDP port on Azure VM. I know the admin. username and password.    Log on to the Azure VM.
Turn off advanced security features on the VM temporally.
Download and install the SHIRT from the Microsoft web-site.
Config. SHIRT with the "Key1" value from the SHIRT in Synapse.
Turn on advanced security features on the VM temporally.

I mark this site down -2 for poor editing buttons, worst I seen in 25 years in IT.